# Puppet node definition

Tags: puppet

That's a simple question that is stolen my time, and getting me crazy. Very simple I can't understand why this regexp is not getting running when I define a new node in puppet:

Hostname: api01.eu-west-1.compute.internal

Node definition

```
3: node ^api\d+\.eu-west-1\.compute\.internal {
4:        include sudo
5:        package { 'vim': ensure => preset } 
6: }
```

My error:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: 
Could not parse for environment production: Could not match 
^api\d+\.eu-west-1\.compute\.internal at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp:3 
on node api01.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

Thanks

Comment: You have `preset` instead of `present`, although that's probably not the source of your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to match nodes using regular expressions you need to put the pattern inside `/.../`, like this:

```
node /^api\d+\.eu-west-1\.compute\.internal/ {
       include sudo
       package { 'vim': ensure => present } 
}
```

You can read more [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#nodes)

Comment: Great but I haven't read that before :S thanks! Works great now.